# How are programs classified as either "bin utilities" or "tools"?

Tags: utilities, terminology

I am frequently hearing the terms "bin utilities" and "tools" when referring to programs. What exactly is the difference between the two?

Both are located at `/usr/bin/` and usually run on command line only. Can you clarify specifically when/why a certain program (for example `objdump`) would be termed a *utilitiy* or a *tool*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`objdump`, at least on most Linux systems, is part of [GNU Binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), which probably explains what you’ve heard. These are tools which allow manipulation of object files, *i.e.* the result of compiling source modules: producing them (using `as`), joining them together (using `ld`), dumping them (using `objdump`), assembling libraries of them (using `ar`) etc. They also include tools which manipulate executables more generally. I tend to view them as “everything necessary to support the C library and C compiler”.

Commands which are included in this project are part of Binutils, others aren’t.

Other than that, I don’t think there’s any universal, agreed-upon distinction between tools and utilities.